# Query DEM Elevation at Point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, terrain

I'd like to be able to pull up a DEM (or create a mosaic of them) and simply query the elevation at points I click. Is this possible using QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean [identify features](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html)?

and also [working with raster data](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/supported_data.html#loading-raster-data-in-qg)?